# After starting hbase in a distributed hadoop ecosystem, the system is getting hanged and had to restart to stabilize the machine

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I installed hadoop in distributed mode in EC2 Ubuntu VMs. It is running fine with 2 datanodes and a seperate namenode. I installed hbase on namenode machine and after few minutes from starting hbase, the entire system is getting hanged. I had to reboot EC2 instance to make the system stable again.

Hadoop Version: 2.10.0

HBase Version: 2.2.3

hbase-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode:9000/hbase</value>
    </property>

    <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/ubuntu/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

    <property>
                <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
            <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/home/ubuntu/hbase/tmp</value>
            <description>Temporary directory on the local filesystem.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop/data/nameNode</value>
        </property>

        <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop/data/dataNode</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>2</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hbase master log file

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.PathIsNotEmptyDirectoryException): `/hbase/WALs/namenode,16020,1583642429033-splitting is non empty': Directory is not empty
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirDeleteOp.delete(FSDirDeleteOp.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:2873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.delete(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:507)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1034)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:922)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2833)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:568)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.delete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.delete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.fs.HFileSystem$1.invoke(HFileSystem.java:372)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:795)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.SplitLogManager.splitLogDistributed(SplitLogManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterWalManager.splitLog(MasterWalManager.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterWalManager.splitLog(MasterWalManager.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterWalManager.splitLog(MasterWalManager.java:271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.ServerCrashProcedure.splitLogs(ServerCrashProcedure.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.ServerCrashProcedure.executeFromState(ServerCrashProcedure.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.procedure.ServerCrashProcedure.executeFromState(ServerCrashProcedure.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.StateMachineProcedure.execute(StateMachineProcedure.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.Procedure.doExecute(Procedure.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.execProcedure(ProcedureExecutor.java:1662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.executeProcedure(ProcedureExecutor.java:1409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor.access$1100(ProcedureExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.procedure2.ProcedureExecutor$WorkerThread.run(ProcedureExecutor.java:1979)
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF while trying to read response from server
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelperClient.vintPrefixed(PBHelperClient.java:402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DataStreamer.java:1073)
2020-03-08 05:13:29,508 INFO  [main-SendThread(namenode:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 66257ms for sessionid 0x170b88ad87c0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

hbase zookeeper log

```
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x170b884854f0002, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-03-08 05:02:00,008 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /172.31.14.122:53892 which had sessionid 0x170b884854f0002
2020-03-08 05:02:00,013 INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2181):] server.PrepRequestProcessor: Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x170b884854f0005
2020-03-08 05:02:00,017 WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x170b884854f0005, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Log files are truncated, only exception are copied.

Comment: What do you have against using EMR?

Comment: It's not a production setup. It is part of my master's project where requirement is to run hadoop ecosystem in ec2 machines not EMR. Can't help there.

Comment: Okay. Have you considered finding CloudFormation, Terraform, Ansible, etc scripts to install Hadoop on EC2 servers for you? Or use Apache Ambari? Basically, if you have never done it before, your cluster performance will be less than optimal once you do manage to just get it installed. At least Ambari can give recommendations on all necessary HDFS and YARN configurations. Also, I would suggest not putting Zookeeper on your Namenode since Namenode needs a fair amount of memory. Basically, first make HDFS highly available (2 Namenodes), which requires 3 or more Zookeeper servers, then add Hbase